# How to call function from modal html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i try to do this in my modal:

```html
<td colspan="4" class="text-center">{{$rootScope.getDate(proposal.date_from)}}</td>

<td colspan="4" class="text-center">{{getDate(proposal.date_to)}}</td>
```

first td outputs nothing
second td outputs {{getDate(proposal.date_to)}} as string
how to call functions correctly? they are defined at both scopes

Answer (score 0):

In your controller attach your `getDate` function to the `$scope`, which should look something like this: `$scope.getDate = function(date) { ... }`. After this you can call `getDate` using this format: `<td colspan="4" class="text-center">{{getDate(proposal.date_to)}}</td>`.